# Outlook: one-click-solution to block sender and mark as read / delete

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, spam-prevention

Using Microsoft Outlook 365 (Version 2303) with Exchange Server from my university, I'm looking for a simple, one-click-solution for junk emails, which should do the following: first, [block the sender](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-a-mail-sender-b29fd867-cac9-40d8-aed1-659e06a706e4) (which automatically moves the email to the junk folder), but second, also mark the email as read (or delete it, but this could also be done automatically via AutoArchive by deleting the trash after a month or so.)

I thought the [**Quick Steps**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-quick-steps-b184f89f-3738-4562-96de-c0244ea830f2) tool would be the way to go, but unfortunately, only some actions are available there: emails can be moved, marked as read, or deleted, but not blocked. (Conversations can be [ignored](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ignore-all-email-messages-in-a-conversation-5ec0c3c2-3440-484e-9aca-0588234d44e9), but as far as I understand, this does not add the sender to the [blocked senders' list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-senders-or-unblock-senders-in-outlook-9bf812d4-6995-4d19-901a-76d6e26939b0).)

So, is there a way to easily block the sender and mark the email as read with one click? (FYI: I do not want to automatically emark mails as read on deletion as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mark-a-message-as-read-or-unread-59b44298-08c2-4eb7-8128-ea0fb7f52720), to avoid deleting unread emails by mistake.)

Comment: This might require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it's not feasible at present using the native features in Outlook.

For current situation, you may need to manually mark the mail as read by either switching the selection in message list or create a quick step for "Mark as read", then put "Block Sender" to the quick access tool bar (Right click "Block Sender" to see the "Add to Quick Access Toolbar" option), so that you can block the sender in one click.

[image]
[image]